# Is there a field type that offers structured entry that gets rendered as a table?

Tags: nodes, entities

In the creation of a content type, is there a field type that offers structured entry that gets rendered as a table?

I'm creating an event node, and on the 'full content' display, there are 'sessions' at the event.

Doing a table in the CKeditor isn't enough, and referencing nodes of a different type is too much.

I need something that starts with these columns and one blank row at the bottom, where the end user/content manager can add information like "Date (datepicker)  |  Discussion Topic  |  Room  |  Timeslot(timepicker)  |  Speaker."

Adding information in each column will cause a new blank row for entry.
When the whole node gets submitted, and rendered in 'full-content' display, a table is rendered with that data, as entered on the backend.

Any suggestions on where to look?

Comment: Have you seen this wiki page? http://groups.drupal.org/node/135229

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at these modules:

- [TableField](http://drupal.org/project/tablefield)
- [CCK Table Field](http://drupal.org/project/cck_table)

Comment: Wow.  That's great.  Can't believe that didn't come up in my searching.  I'll check it out.  Will mark 'answered' if it's a good fit.

Answer (score 1):

This is my favorite Drupal 7 solution to this problem: Instead of "referencing" another node or entity, bring the entity to your node form. It's called [Field Collection](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection). Basically it embeds an entity creation form inside the node form.

There is also a formatter that shows the data as a table: http://drupal.org/project/field_collection_table.

Comment: Interesting module suggerstion, though it only have a beta version.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably best to create a custom module, if you have a special ordering of table and data, especially  when there is a single entry form and a lot of tables where they will go.

You will find more on http://drupal.org/developing/modules.